# VB.Net 5.0 Core Console Application - System.Configuration (and My.Settings) unavailable

Tags: vb.net, system.configuration

I need to set some persisting configuration info for the console app I'm writing with VB .Net Core (.Net 5.0).

Acc. to the documentation, `System.Configuration` should do the trick but Visual Studio goes: `Imports statement unnecessary`, and the `My` namespace only has `InternalXmlHelper`.  `My.Settings` is simply non-existent.

I've tried to read the documentation and yesterday searched all over for anyone with similar issues but have found nothing so far.

Some help would be appreciated. :')

Edit: I've also checked to see if adding System.Configuration.dll as a reference is possible, and it is also unavailable.

Edit Conclusive: Found out that .Net Core does not support System.Configuration. Nevermind then. Hope I can find an alternative.

Comment: I've not done it in VB but you ought to look into using an appsettings.json file in .NET Core. That's probably read-only though, so probably look at using your own XML or JSON file(s).

Comment: [Updating the Default Settings file in a WinForms .NET 5 Visual Basic app fails. Issue #6784](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6784) -- VS 17 milestone.